# Jquery Anchor Elements Moving to New-Line on Hide

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to JQuery (and JavaScript/AJAX in general) and am encountering a problem with hiding elements.

When I use the code below the animation works and the element is hidden but as it is being hidden it is shifted onto a new line along with everything after it. This happens with horizontal hide as well but not with opacity.

Is there a way to stop this from happening or am I missing something out somewhere? The links appear on a line like this:

**Related Tags:** Tag1 Tag2 Tag3

Code Snippets:

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="JQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="test.js"></script>

<strong>Related Tags: </strong>

<a href=#>Tag1</a>
<a href=#>Tag2</a>
<a href=#>Tag3</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
     $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).animate({height: 'hide' },"Fast");
    });
});
```

Thanks in Advance,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's happening is that you're animating over the `height` attribute. Manually setting height would imply block view, and that's why you're being shifted to a new line.

If you don't have a problem with it, you could switch to `fadeOut` for hiding, and that probably won't cause the same error. Otherwise, the dirty workaround would have to be setting `float: left` on the anchors. For this to be a neat solution, you'd have to put them in a container, and `clear` them (because floating objects don't occupy any space in their parent unless they're cleared)

```
<p>
    <a style="float: left;">...</a>
    <a style="float: left;">...</a>
    <a style="float: left;">...</a>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Shifting like that probably turns it into a block element, which will put it on a new line will visible. I would suggest:

```
a { float: left; }
```

That turns them all into blocks but keeps them side-by-side. I would also suggest using:

```
$(this).slideUp();
```

rather than animating height.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an inline object cannot have a height specified in HTML. I'm not sure exactly what's happening here but it appears jQuery is compensating by changing the anchor to be a block-level element.

As for how to resolve it, I'm not 100% sure this will work but perhaps if you specify a style of "display: inline-block" for your anchor tags this may resolve the issue (inline-block would allow them to have a height and still behave as you'd expect). If you were to make them all "display: block; float: left;" I'm pretty sure that'd solve it too.